# Android: is possible to Improve my code to download XML from URL?

Tags: android, xml, url, download

In internet I got a code to download the text of an XML from a URL. The works ok. My problem is that I have to download many XML simultaneously.

I can to improve my code to make downloading faster? thanks

**XMLParser**

```
public XmlReader(String monumento) {

    this.monumento = monumento;     
}

public void get() {

    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(this);

        InputStream inputStream = new URL(URL + monumento + ".xml").openStream();
        reader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currTag = true;
    currTagVal = "";

    if (localName.equals("monumento")) {
        post = new HorariosTarifasObj();
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    currTag = false;

    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("horarios")) {
        post.setHorarios(currTagVal);

    } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tarifas")) {
        post.setTarifas(currTagVal);

    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("monumento")) {
        posts.add(post);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (currTag) {
        currTagVal = currTagVal + new String(ch, start, length);
        currTag = false;
    }
}
```

**ACTIVITY.java**

```
class tareaAsyncHorariosTarifas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    XmlReader helper;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        helper = new XmlReader(monumento);
        helper.get();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (HorariosTarifasObj post : helper.posts) {
            builder.append(post.getHorarios());
        } 
        if(builder.toString().equals("")) {
            horario2.setText("-");
        } else {
            horario2.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
        }

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (HorariosTarifasObj post : helper.posts) {
            builder.append(post.getTarifas());
        }
        if(builder.toString().equals("")) {
            tarifa2.setText("-");
        } else {
            tarifa2.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the code which executes the AsyncTask? Is it in a loop for each XML file?

Comment: No, it execute in fragments

Comment: ok, can you at least post code which calls AsyncTask for each XML file?

Comment: `new tareaAsyncHorariosTarifas().execute();` in onCreate method

Comment: Well, I was going to propose putting your code which requests and parse each xml file on a seperate thread, but you already sort of do that with Async tasks :(

Comment: Then my code is correct?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, thats about as much refactoring as I know how to do.